# Database size via WMI in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, wmi

Is there a way to find out the size of a SQL Server database using WMI from .NET?

I've had a look at the [WMI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180499.aspx) but I'm not clear how I'd be able to locate that information.

We're using SQL Server 2008.

-dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this property via Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo. Give this a try: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.size.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a tangential answer, but whenever I want to play with WMI, I first take a quick look with [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/scripto2.mspx), Microsoft's WMI browser.

Doing so against SQL **Express 2005**, the only WMI functionality seems to be with regard to the server itself, and not for any of the databases.